# iPhone-style "Stocks" app?

Tags: applications

I was playing around with a friend's iPhone the other day. I'm a total anti-Apple, but I can recognize niceties when I see them. The Stocks app on the iPhone seemed much more concise and useful than any I've tried on Android.

Specifically I like how it is laid out with all your pertinent information right there. Symbol, price, and change. **WITH** the chart also shown on the screen. The little top section with the symbols is scrollable within its own space if you have more than fit in it, but the chart stays where it is.

Does anyone know if there is a port (or highly similar app) of the iPhone's "Stocks" app available for Android?

Ideally, it needs to be an app which can also handle symbols for mutual funds well (with charting), as my investments are all in mutual funds, not direct stocks.

I've tried the Yahoo stocks app, Google's, TD Bank's and most recently E*TRADE's. But they all seem to have a very cluttered feel, or don't bring together your basic information all in one place leaving you to flip between several screens.

Cheers, and thanks!

[image: iPhone Stock app screenshot]

Comment: As it's very unlikely that people here are iPhone users, and so won't be familiar with the iPhone's apps, it might be helpful if you can list what features of the iPhone's app you like, and what problems you've had with Android apps you've tried.

Comment: Updated with a screenie and more details. Good point.

Answer (score 3):

Try Google's own 'Finance' app from the market.

> Finance for Android brings you streaming real-time quotes in this stock quote and portfolio application. It synchronizes with your Google Finance portfolios, allows quick access to charts and lets you view the latest market and company news

Comment: You still need to go to multiple screens to see the same information. One of the things I like about the iPhone one is that all your basic information is on one screen.